# Chrome Extension: Opening Jquery Ui Dialog

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, xhtml, google-chrome-extension

I'm very new to chrome extension development.. I got basic idea from google's tutorial and some help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358939/opening-a-jquery-ui-dialog-using-chrome-extension)
here is what i have done so far

background.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script>
            chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, 
                {file:"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css", 
                    runAt:"document_start"}, 
                function() { alert('Added css'); });
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, 
                {file:"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js", 
                    runAt:"document_start"}, 
                function () {
                    alert("loaded js");
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, 
                    {file:"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"}, 
                    function () {
                        alert("loaded js2");
                        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:"popup.js"}, function() {alert("did it pop up yet?");});
                    });
                });
            });


        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Manifest.json file

```
{
"name": "demo",
"version": "2.0",
"description": "Jquery Dialog in Chrome",
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "favicon.ico",
"default_title": "Dialog Box"
},
"background_page": "background.html",
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*","http://jquery.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js","popup.js"]
    }
  ],
"permissions": [
 "tabs","http://localhost/","http://*/*"
]
}
```

And popup.js file where my ui dialog is

```
$(function() {
    alert('in popup');
var NewDialog = $('<div id="MenuDialog"><p>This is your dialog content, which can be multiline and dynamic.</p></div>');
NewDialog.dialog({
modal: true,
title: "title",
show: 'clip',
hide: 'clip',
buttons: [
    {text: "Submit", click: function() {doSomething()}},
    {text: "Cancel", click: function() {$(this).dialog("close")}}
]
});
NewDialog.dialog("open");
});
```

I'm getting the alerts from the background.html but not from popup.js, jquery ui Dialog also not appears. I tried to debug it

I opened gmail and clicked on extension console is showing 4 errors >

```
Error during tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#inbox". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

Comment: As i understood, you try to open this url, when you have not loggined. You need pay attantion on athorification

Comment: it is a google chrome extension.. when I click on extension it should inject jquery and ui file in tab and should open div as dialog (popup.js).. but not opening ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error message is quite clear. You don't have permissions for `mail.google.com` the on `https` protocol.
Add `https://mail.google.com/*` or for broader access `*://*.google.com/*` to your permissions.

Comment: Yes that's right. For all urls you can also use `<all_urls>`. See [**Match patterns**](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html) for further details