# Chrome Extension: Inject JQuery Dialog to a page by content script

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome-extension

I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616607/chrome-extension-opening-jquery-ui-dialog/13583586#13583586) for injecting jquery dialog, but haven't succeed.
I got a dialog on the page, but it's shown transparent. 
It seems that jquery-ui.css was not loaded correctly. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: We cannot help without code.

Comment: show some code... even if your code is exactly the same as for the link you supplied, you might have missed something, added something...

Comment: Code the same as for the link, but somehow it doesn't work like described. I copy and paste it.

Comment: Try replacing the `background.html` with a `background.js`. See how they do it in the documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to download **jquery-ui.css** file and put it to plugin directory and link to it in **manifest.json** like that:

```
"content_scripts": [{
"matches": ["http://*/*", "http://jquery.com/*"],
    "css": ["jquery-ui.css"],
    "js": ["jquery.js", "jquery-ui.js", "popup.js"]
}]
```

I don't know why the following injection doesn't work:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css",
        runAt: "document_start"
    },

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js",
        runAt: "document_start"
    },

    function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            file: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"
        },

        function () {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                file: "popup.js"
            });
        });
    });
 });
```

so I downloaded **jquery.js**, **jquery-ui.js**, put them to plugin directory and linked in **manifest.json** as mention above. Then removed all injections:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, 
        {
            file:"popup.js", 
            runAt:"document_start"}
        }););
```

As result I got formatted jQuery dialog on any pages

Comment: The reason the above script doesn't work is because you are calling `executeScript` with the CSS file instead of `insertCSS`.

Answer (score 0):

The last time i needed that i had to write the CSS directly into the document, by requesting the whole CSS over an Ajax request and place it into the header. I dont remember why i did that, but i'm pretty sure i would not have done it, when i found a better solution. Also note if its just the dialog, you really dont need the whole CSS. For my "solution" it would be better to use only what you actually need.